# How can I make two objects interact

Tags: animation

I am making an animation where a person sits down on sofa. I need to make it such that when the person sits on the sofa or presses it with his hand, it deforms. However in my case, when he presses on the sofa, his hands goes trough the sofa. How can I fix this problem?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use **Dynamic Paint** simulation, which is the recommended way, and generate very vivid result.

- Set Sofa as **Canvas** object, and choose **Displace** for *Surface Type*.
- Set character as **Brush** object, and choose **Mesh Volume** for *Paint Source*.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**[Example File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ojv5B6Lb-3N0hkaEV2VDgwTTQ/view?usp=sharing)**

Comment: I try to do this but in when I click on the person (it is a .mhx file exported from MakeHuman)in object mode. I remark that there is no Dynamic paint option. I edit my example.

Comment: According to your updated screenshot, you are currently selecting amarture, not the object itself. You can try select the mesh object correctly, then you'll find it. Good luck. :)

Comment: I discover that when I export the .mhx, I did not used any mehs for this raison I did not see the mesh in layer 4. Thnx

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out. :)

Comment: For the records, I like raisins too.